# How to create API of my rails application like facebook and twitter API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Hi i want to create API of my existing Rails 3 application

```
             like facebook and twitter API.
```

A call will come to my application and appropriate result should be return in json format.

Is there any best rails gem or plugin exist for it with clear usage.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails itself is the gem for building api. I recommend [Ryan Bates's casts](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=37) about apis.

Answer (score 1):

Wide topic but this should help: http://blog.gomiso.com/2011/06/27/building-a-platform-api-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

acts_as_api gem may help you..